# Downloading multiple files simultaneously in blackberry using webworks and cordova 2.9

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I'm working on an app which needs to download some files from a webserver and store them on the device so they can be used offline. The code I'm using works fine in Android and iOS, however I'm having difficulty downloading more than one file on blackberry 10.

From looking at the web console it seems that the success callback is executed successfully for the first file, but not for any of the subsequent files. The fail callback is not being called for the subsequent files either.

I'm using cordova 2.9, and I've included all the required webworks plugins. I have set up access to my domain in config.xml and have set the access_shared permission.

I've also edited the cordova FileTransfer.download function to call the webworks download api "blackberry.io.filetransfer.download".

Below is the JavaScript code that I've written.

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    //replace list with your files you wish to download
    var files = ["files/file1.txt", "files/file2.txt", "files/dir1/file3.txt"];
    initiateDownload(files);
    //getFSRoot(files);
}

var filesToDownload = 0;
var fileList = new Array();
var failedFileList;
var numFailedFiles = 0;
var currentFileIndex;
var retryCount = 0;
var root;

function isOnline(){
    var bIsOnline = false;

    if (navigator.connection.type != Connection.NONE && navigator.connection.type != Connection.UNKNOWN)
    {
        bIsOnline = true;
    }

    return bIsOnline;
}

function initiateDownload(files){
    alert("initiate download");

    failedFileList = new Array();
    filesToDownload = files.length;

    blackberry.io.sandbox = false;
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
    {
        currentFileIndex = i;
        console.log("initiate download of file index " + i + " File Name: " + files[i]);
        getFile(files[i]);
    }

}


function getFile(filePath)
{
    //TODO: Do we need to make this function recursive to serialize asynchronous downloads?
    console.log("START of function getFile() for " + filePath);

    window.requestFileSystem(
        LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem)
        {
            console.log("Success getting filesystem for filePath: " + filePath);
            createDirs(fileSystem.root, filePath, -1);
        },
        function(error){
            console.log("Failed to get the filesystem for filePath: " + filePath);
        }
    );
}

function createDirs(parentDir, filePath, index)
{
    console.log("createDirs params ===> parentDir=" + parentDir.toURL() + " filePath=" + filePath + " index=" + index); 
    arrDirs = filePath.split("/");

    if (index >= (arrDirs.length - 1))
    {
        createFile(arrDirs[index], parentDir, filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        dirName = "myapp";

        if (index >= 0)
        {
            dirName = arrDirs[index];
        }

        //if device is Blackberry, build up a full directory path as we are trying to install outside of sandbox
        var path, dirToCreate = ""
        if(device.platform = "BlackBerry"){

            path = "myapp/";
            console.log("JHPaths ======> arrDirs = " + arrDirs + " index = " +index);
            for (i = 0; i <= index; i++){
                path += arrDirs[i] + "/";
                console.log("path = " + path + " i = " + i + " index = " +  index);
            }

            dirToCreate = blackberry.io.home + "/" + path;
            dirToCreate = dirToCreate.substring(0, dirToCreate.length - 1);
            console.log("JHPaths Trying to create " + dirToCreate);
            dirName = dirToCreate;
        }

        parentDir.getDirectory(dirName, {create: true, exclusive: false},
                               function (directoryEntry) {
                                    console.log("Got directory " + directoryEntry.fullPath);
                                    createDirs(directoryEntry, filePath, index + 1);
                               },
                               function (error) {console.log("Failed to get directory " + dirName + " Error code : " + error.code);});
    }
}

function createFile(fileName, parentDir, filePath)
{   
    parentDir.getFile(
        fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false},
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry)
        {
            localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;

            if (isOnline())
            {
                console.log("Before remove");
                fileEntry.remove(
                    function(){
                        console.log("FileEntry remove() was successful");
                    },
                    function(){
                        console.log("FileEntry remove() was failed");
                    }
                );
                console.log("After remove");
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                //replace URL with the URL code you wish to download from
                var baseURL = "http://<ip-address>/WebFolder/";

                var uri = encodeURI(baseURL + filePath);
                fullFilePath = blackberry.io.home + "/myapp/" + filePath;
                fileTransfer.download(
                    uri,
                    /*localPath,*/
                    fullFilePath,
                    function(entry) {
                        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
                        /*if(currentFileIndex < fileList.length){
                            currentFileIndex++;
                        }*/
                        if (device.platform == "iOS")
                        {
                            console.log("Setting file metadata");
                            parentDir.getFile(
                                fileName, {create:false, exclusive: false},
                                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry)
                                {
                                    fileEntry.setMetaData(
                                        function(){console.log("Set metadata for " + fileEntry.fullPath)},
                                        function(){console.log("Set metadata failed for " + fileEntry.fullPath)},
                                        {"com.apple.MobileBackup": 1}
                                    );
                                },
                                function getFileFailed(fileError)
                                {
                                    console.log("Get file failed:" + fileError.code);
                                }
                            );
                        }

                        filesToDownload--;

                        if (filesToDownload == 0 && failedFileList.length == 0)
                        {
                            //Call to retry failed Files
                                                        }   
                        else if(failedFileList.length > 0){
                            if(retryCount < 1){
                                retryFailedFiles();
                            }
                            else{
                                                                }
                        }
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log("Cache file download error source " + error.source);
                        console.log("Cache file download error target " + error.target);
                        console.log("Cache file download error code " + error.code);

                        //failedFileList[numFailedFiles++] = filePath;
                        failedFileList[numFailedFiles++] = filePath;
                        filesToDownload--;

                        if (filesToDownload == 0 && failedFileList.length == 0)
                        {

                        }
                        else if(failedFileList.length > 0){
                            if(retryCount < 1){
                                retryFailedFiles();
                            }
                            else{

                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        function getFileFailed(fileError)
        {
            console.log("Create file failed:" + fileError.code);

            filesToDownload--;

            /*if (filesToDownload == 0)
            {
                callbackDeferred.resolve();
            }*/
        }
    );
}

function retryFailedFiles(){
    console.log("Retrying failed files");
    retryCount++;
    initiateDownload(failedFileList);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out what's going on?